# Flexible member array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

What I need (but in C++):

```
struct Element{
   bool deleted;
   T value;
}
struct Chunk{
   Chunk* prev;
   // other data
   Element elements[];       // C99 flexible array member!

   static make(std::size_t capacity){
       Chunk *chunk = static_cast<Chunk *>(std::malloc(sizeof(Chunk) + sizeof(Element) * capacity));
      // init data
      return chunk;
   }
}
```

But C++ does not have 'flexible array member'. So I did something like this:

```
struct Element{
   bool deleted;
   T value;
}
struct alignas(Element) Chunk{   // Chunk is always POD
   Chunk* prev;
   // other data

   Element *elements() {
       return static_cast<Element *>(static_cast<void *>(
           reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(this) + sizeof(Chunk)
       ));
   }

   static make(std::size_t capacity){
       Chunk *chunk = static_cast<Chunk *>(std::malloc(sizeof(Chunk) + sizeof(Element) * capacity));
      // init data
      // DO NOT INIT elements here. Will be placement newed' later.
      return chunk;
   }
}
```

The question is - is this correct? Or does this cause UB? Does it correctly aligned? Is this better than `Element elements[1]` trick?

P.S. There are several workarounds to this problem on stackoverflow, but I didn't get which of them correct, after all.

Comment: Looks like you are reinventing `std::vector` here.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - thx, but no :)

Comment: Ok, then I don't understand that question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen What’s wanted is VLAs in C++ as the last member of a `struct`, making a variable-sized `struct`. C supports this, but C++ does not; the question is what workarounds are good and which are not. Is that any clearer?

Comment: Why do you need the elements to be stored next to the `Chunk* prev` element, instead of dynamically allocated somewhere else?

Comment: @DanielH Not at all. Either heap allocation is fine, in which case they are reinventing `std::vector`, or it's not, in which case their approach makes no sense. Apparently it's the latter, but I'm not quite sure yet what they are asking.

Comment: @DanielH - well, I'm trying to do something like deque. And I can dynamycally allocate them. But this will require two more times memory allocation, and which is more important, iteration will require more inderections. I would be happy to live with deque, but in all tested cases it MUCH slower then my implementation. (I think due to inner map ussage)

Comment: @BaummitAugen Vector is resizable; this isn’t. This isn’t reinventing `std::vector`, but instead std::deque.

Comment: Are you trying to make a pool of objects, in an array, with a flag stating whether the object is "in use" or not?  I think a map would be easier.

Comment: @tower120 Why does `std::deque` not work? And I think the standard solution is to say that a `Chunk` has a maximum size, and to have a non-flexible fixed-size array member.

Comment: @Robinson What I'm trying to do - is to make container which can be iterable simuteniously from multiple threads, and allow erase/emplace on the fly. I need deque struct for this.

Comment: @DanielH `std::deque` work, but it TOOO SLOW.

Comment: If your actually issue is that `std::deque` is too slow, you may want to ask about that instead, MCVE and benchmark results included of course. Someone will probably either figure out what you are doing wrong or suggest a useful alternative.

Comment: @BaummitAugen What I ask - is this correct implementation of Flexible array member in terms of allocation, access, memory alignment? It has nothing to do with deque/vector, etc.

Comment: @tower120 what about flexible arrays do you need that isn't provided by a deque/vector?

Comment: **If it is too slow, then you are probably compiling the debug version** with all validation turned on... Otherwise, performance should not be an issue for most application provide that your algorithm and container make sense...

Comment: @Phil1970 It is 2.5 times slower then `vector` on iteration of 100'000 ints. More - if size is smaller.

Comment: `Element elements[]` Arrays must be with a specific size at compile time.

Comment: For POD, I think it should works... However, if virtual functions or inheritance are used, it can easily cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @Phil1970 You mean, if `T` will have virtual functions? Or Chunk? Chunk is POD always.

Comment: If it is slower than vector, then why are you not using `vector`? Also, if you allocate blocks, then why not used a predefined size instead of VLA? Also, your custom code might be less robust than STL.

Comment: @Phil1970 I can not emplace_back/front to vector while iterating. If I will use predefined size, either all chunks must be the same size, either each next chunk must have different type (then I can't iterate them, have pointer to head Chunk). Sure it can be less robust, STL just not have what I needed.

Comment: **Don't reinvent the wheel!**

Comment: I see two problems: your requirements and the task at hand are not stated (its completely unclear what your use cases are), second the code is problematic (for instance mixing malloc and placement new, but there are other problems; however before looking into this it would be good to first state what is the problem at hand and that does not mean what data structure or solution you already have in mind

Comment: Yes, perhaps a better strategy would be to clearly state the problem you're trying to solve.  It may be that this "too slow" is simply the choice of algorithm.

Comment: @Raindrop7 Yes, but that isn’t the case in C and the question is how to emulate that in C++.

Comment: @tower120 What compiler are you using? Some compilers, like G++, provide VLA support in C++ as an extension.

Comment: @DanielH I think I'm using gcc >=7 and clang/c2 . And smthg like `Element elements[];` just works, but I need portable solution, preferably without including .c files in project. I know start thinking, that the way that I do it - is the most correct way - it does not violate "array" bounds, like with 'Elements elements[1]', and it have correct alignment with `struct alignas(Element) Chunk`.

Comment: @tower120 I still think that the best solution is to use a fixed-size array instead of a variable-length one, but either way you’ll also need a `size` member to store how many elements there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up with this solution:

```
template<class Header, class T>
class FlexibleMemberArray {
    struct alignas(T) AlignedHeader : Header{};

    Header* self(){
        return static_cast<Header*>(this);
    }

protected:
    static Header* make(const int capacity) {
        Header *chunk = static_cast<Header *>(std::malloc(sizeof(AlignedHeader) + sizeof(T) * capacity));
        return chunk;
    }

    inline T *elements() {
        return static_cast<T *>(static_cast<void *>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(self()) +
                                                          sizeof(AlignedHeader)));
    }
};
```

Which can be used as:

```
struct Chunk : public FlexibleMemberArray<Chunk, int>{
    int capacity;
    static void* operator new(std::size_t sz, int capacity) {
        Chunk* self = make(capacity);
        self->capacity = capacity;
        return self;
    }

     using FlexibleMemberArray::elements;
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Chunk> chunk {new (30) Chunk};

    for(int i=0;i<chunk->capacity;i++){
        chunk->elements()[i] = i;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<chunk->capacity;i++){
        std::cout << chunk->elements()[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```